# How do I install the SSH2 extensions of PHP?

Tags: package-management, ssh, 8.04, php

I want to be able to run PHP functions like [`ssh2_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php). But, those functions are not available on my machine. What do I need to do to install them?

I am using Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu package index lists [libssh2-php](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssh2-php&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) packages for several tastes (lucid to oneiric). You can look if your system has all the required software, download the [libssh2-php.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libssh2-php) from Lucid and install it

```
sudo dpkg -i libssh2-php*.deb
```

or use `gdebi`.

If this don't work you can download the [source code](http://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.2.9.tar.gz) from [libssh2.org](http://www.libssh2.org/) and compile it for yourself.

Comment: This probably won't work because of the version differences.

Comment: ACK, thatswhy I recommended to look if Adam has all the necessary software installed.

Comment: You can try to grab it with php-pear :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command for install ssh2

```
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev
sudo pecl install -a ssh2-0.12
echo 'extension=ssh2.so' | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/ssh2.ini > /dev/null
sudo php5enmod ssh2
```